# Java; ArrayList<T> indexof

Tags: java

So hi everyone! I've worked with this project to keep a record of a baseball season and I have confront this problem with my ArrayList usage:

.
.
.

```
private ArrayList<Team> list1 = new ArrayList<Team>();

Team something = new Team("Somename");
Team somethingelse = new Team("Someothername");
```

and then I used some setters like:

```
something.setPoints(1);
somethingelse.setPoints(2);
```

and then:

```
list1.add(something);
list1.add(somethingelse);
```

but here comes the problem:

```
int help1 = list1.indexOf(something);
System.out.println(help1);
```

returns -1

but the list contains those objects:

```
for (Team d: list1) {
      System.out.println(d);
 }
```

The output is that toString() -method I wrote to the Team class...

and then I tried it with

```
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list2.add(1);

list2.add(2);

int help2 = list2.indexOf(1);
System.out.println(help2);
```

returns 0

So basically what I am asking is that is that the right way of using indexOf when the list contains objects which have multiple values?

Answer (score 3):

You need to override [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) method in your `Team` class. So when you do `list1.indexOf(something);`, the [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method knows how to locate the object `something`

Comment: whenever you overriding equal consider overriding hashcode method too

Answer (score 2):

you need to override hashcode and equals of Team class!

Comment: Hashcode is not necessary for ArrayList, though it is good practice to override both if you override one.

Comment: Your class specification always must be correct regardless of whether they are using in arraylist or hashmap. for further reading refer to Effective java Item 9: Always override hashCode when you override equals

Answer (score 1):

As per the Java doc of the [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More
>   formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null
>   : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

So you essentially need to `override` the `equals()` method with whatever you want to match, for instance:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(object obj)
{
     if(obj instanceof Team)
     {
          Team t = (Team) obj;
          return t.getName().equals(this.getName());
     }
     return false;

}
```

This code is untested but it should do what you need. In this case, I consider two teams to be equal if they have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If that `something` object is the *same* instance all through your example, everything should be fine, since `Object.equals` is being used, which returns true for the same instance.

If, however, you are creating another object with the same values and all, `Object.equals` will return `false`. You need to implement an `equals` and `hashCode` method that considers your object fields.